# correlation of 1/X

Tags: correlation

My question is the following.
If the correlation between the log-returns of X and Y is rho, what would be the correlation between the log returns  of 1/X and Y ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you know about $\log(1/X)=-\log X$ ?

Answer (score 5):

A few identities will be helpful to remember.

$$\log(1/X)=\log(X^{-1})=-\log(X)$$

$$
cor(X,Y)=\dfrac{cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{var(X)var(Y)}}
$$

$$
var(X)=cov(X,X)\\
$$

$$
cov(aX,bY)=ab\times cov(X,Y)\\
var(aX)=a^2var(X)
$$

(This last one means that $var(-X)=var(X)$.

Combining these:

$$
cor(-\log(X),\log(Y))\\
=-corr(\log(X),\log(Y)\\
=-\rho
$$